# one-way operations in web service c#

Tags: c#, web-services, wsdl

Dear All,,
I need to consume web service and they send me WSDL. I was added it to service reference and when I called method GetDataWarehouse() in WSDL I got error..

"The one-way operation 'SubmitAccessList' on ServiceContract 'DataWarehouseWebService' is configured for transaction flow. Transactions cannot be flowed over one-way operations."

SubmitAccessList is one of method in WSDL but I wonder because I didn`t used it for now..

Can you give me a hint?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, what you use is pretty irrelevant - WDSL is "all or nothing" in that the tool looks at it all, or not at all. You can argue this is a limitation -it is - but in most cases not a relevant one.

What is funny that this looks - never experienced this myself - like an error, as in the provider got a very funny non-legal setup for his web service, which means and hints there is nothing you can do. It seems they implmenent a one way web service.... and the service contract is putting in transactions. BAD combo.... a transaction can not be properly handled without additional communication and feedback to the sender, so the one way paradigm (fire and forget) is not logically compatible.

If noone else has a better ansqwer... I would say contact the web service provider for support (and have them fix their service).

I gladly take a correction on this if anyone has a better idea ;)

Comment: Agree with TomTom - that its most likely an issue with the service itself and you need to contact whoever is responsible for the service. Most likely the method in question `SubmitAccessList` is having `[OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]` and also a 
`[TransactionFlow]` attribute with anything but `TransactionFlowOption.NotAllowed`. This is not allowed for reasons explained above. `TransactionFlowOption.NotAllowed` is the only valid value allowed for a one way contract